# Specify div width when using CSS display:table

Tags: html, css

I am creating a list of courses. I want to display it as a table, but with each row clickable as a link, so I can't use a conventional table.

To do that I am using divs, using display:table;

```
< div class = "table" > 
< a class = "table-row" href = "tutorials.php?course=Life Only&grade=Freshman&semester=1&subject=Key Terms" >
< div class = "table-cell" > Life Only < /div>
<div class="table-cell">Freshman</div > 
< div class = "table-cell" > Semester 1 < /div> 
<div class="table-cell">Key Terms</div >
 < /a>

<a class="table-row" href="tutorials.php?course=Life Only&grade=Freshman&semester=2&subject=Key Terms"> 
<div class="table-cell">Life Only</div > 
< div class = "table-cell" > Freshman < /div> 
<div class="table-cell">Semester 2</div > 
< div class = "table-cell" > Key Terms < /div>
</a > 
etc . . .
```

But the result that I am getting has all of the divs with no spacing. Even when I declare a fixed width for the class table-cell with !important.

```
e.g.:
Life OnlyFreshmanSemester 1Key Terms
Life OnlyFreshmanSemester 2Key Terms
Life OnlyFreshmanSemester 3Key Terms
Life OnlySophmoreSemester 1Key Terms
Life OnlySophmoreSemester 2Key Terms
Life OnlySophmoreSemester 3Key Terms
Life OnlyJuniorSemester 1Key Terms
Life OnlyJuniorSemester 2Key Terms
Life OnlyJuniorSemester 3Key Terms
Life OnlySeniorSemester 1Key Terms
Life OnlySeniorSemester 2Key Terms
Life OnlySeniorSemester 3Key Terms
```

This is the CSS that I am using:

```
.table { 
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
.table a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.table-row { 
    display:table-row;
}
.table-cell { 
    display:table-cell; 
    display:inline;
}
```

I even tried some code to right pad the elements based on the length of the variable minus a fixed width, but while it spaced them out, it wasn't consistent due to the variable spacing of the font.

Any ideas on how I can fix the width of the elements so it displays like a table?

[Here is a link to this code in codepen](https://codepen.io/birwin/pen/mddjdqP)

Comment: `< div` must be `<div` and `< /a>` must be `</a>`. Don't add whitespace where no whitespace belongs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually the code I pasted in didn't have the leading spaces. Somehow it was added when I pasted it into the question editor.

Comment: How does this make any sense `display:table-cell; 
    display:inline;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While entering this in codepen, I discovered the answer. I changed the display:inline; statement in the .table-cell CSS to read display:inline-block;

It then accepted a width statement  width:100px;